# Finding graphical interface for GDB

Tags: windows, gui, debugging

Recently, I start to debug my Fortran code with GDB. There are so many command-line which employing them is difficult for me.

I want to know is there any graphical user interface (GUI) for GDB that works properly in Windows 64-bit?

My preference is to use GUI that Windows-friendly and has no difficulty with installation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE is an Integrated Development Environment for C/C++ & FORTRAN it:

- can work with a number of toolchains including the gcc toolchain
- Has a GUI debugger that is a wrapper for GDB
- Full breakpoints support:

  - Code breakpoints
  - Data breakpoints (read, write and read/write)
  - Breakpoint conditions (break only when an expression is true)
  - Breakpoint ignore counts (break only after certain number of hits)
  - Display local function symbols and arguments
- User-defined watches (support for watching user-defined types through scripting)
- Call stack
- Disassembly
- Custom memory dump
- Switch between threads
- View CPU registers
- Is completely free, Gratis & Open Source
- Can be extended through plug-ins
- Runs on Windows, XP/Vista/7/8.x/10 *both 64 bit & 32 bit*
- Runs on Linux 32 and 64-bit
- Runs on Mac OS-X

*Note that for full GUI debug support you will need to build your code with debug symbols and with optimisation turned off.*